# Selenium Locators for Ant Design

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, antd, software-quality

Hello good people of the internet.
I'm looking for a locator bank or a github repository enlisting all the necessary locators for the Ant Design (Antd - React) library for Selenium Web Driver (Java).

Currently, I've been trying to figure out all the locators manually which kind of feels like reinventing the wheel!

Any help in this area will be very helpful.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.